# UPDATE MySQL table based DATETIME Column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have the following tables: `cash_billings_bills_articles` and `articles_pricehistory`

[image: articles_pricehistory]

[image: cash_billings_bills_articles]

I need to update the `cashbillingbillarticle_cost` column according to the `articles_pricehistory` in his based date. The logic is to select all historical records date less the date of transaction `cashbillingbill_date` and capture the most recent cost of selected filter.

This is my desired result:

[image: result]

This is what I tried to do:

```
UPDATE cash_billings_bills_articles 
    LEFT JOIN articles_pricehistory USING(article_id)
    LEFT JOIN cash_billings_bills USING(cashbillingbill_id)
SET cash_billings_bills_articles.cashbillingbillarticle_cost = articles_pricehistory.articlepricehistory_cost
    WHERE cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbill_date >= articles_pricehistory.articlepricehistory_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think of this in terms of a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE cash_billings_bills_articles cbba 
    SET cbba.cashbillingbillarticle_cost = (SELECT ph.articlepricehistory_cost
                                            FROM articles_pricehistory ph JOIN
                                                 cash_billings_bills cbb
                                                 USING (cashbillingbill_id)
                                            WHERE ph.article_id = cbba.article_id AND
                                                 ph.articlepricehistory_date <= cbb.cashbillingbill_date
                                            ORDER BY ph.articlepricehistory_date DESC
                                            LIMIT 1
                                           );
```

Comment: i got some syntax problems on line 4

Comment: @JonathanEdgardo . . . I probably fixed that when I added `join`.